Flux calculation - what did I do wrong?
The exercise asks to calculate the flux of $\mathbf{F}=(4x,4y,z^2)$ through the surface $x^2+y^2=25, 0\le z \le 2$
I calculated using Gauss' theorem and  I obtained $500\pi$, which is, as the teacher says, the correct answer.
The exercise also asks to calculate it as
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F}·d\mathbf{S}=\iint_S\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{S})·\mathbf{n}\ dS$$
Using cylindrical coordinates:  $\mathbf{S}=(5\cos\theta, 5\sin\theta, z), \theta \in [0,2\pi], z \in [0, 2]$
And $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{S})=(20\cos\theta, 20\sin\theta, z^2)$
And the unitary normal vector of the surface is $\mathbf{n}= \frac{\mathbf{S}_\theta \times \mathbf{S}_z}{\lVert \mathbf{S}_\theta \times \mathbf{S}_z \rVert}=(5\cos\theta,5\sin\theta,0)$
And $dS=5d\theta dz$
So
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F}·d\mathbf{S}=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2(20\cos^2(\theta)+20\sin^2(\theta))5dzd\theta=400\pi\neq500\pi$$
What did I do wrong?

It looks like you are missing a - sign in the normal vector, as it stands $\vec n \cdot \vec S \ne 0$

@WW1 I checked it and even if that was the problem I think that would not obtain $500\pi$

The unit normal vector should be $\pm (\sin \theta , -\cos\theta)$

you got $500 \pi$ using Gauss' Theorem, which does not use the normal vector

But $\mathbf{n}·\mathbf{S}$ do not need to be $0$, I do not think I miscalculated the normal vector

When you use Gauss’s Theorem you must have a closed surface — you have included the flux across the top and bottom disks, as well. The exercise as given did not include those, so the $500\pi$ answer is incorrect. Your normal vector is right except for its length!

THANK YOU! I thought that, so I substracted to the flux calculated with Gauss' Theorem the flux through the top and bottom disk and it worked!

The issue lies in the use of Gauss' theorem (the divergence theorem): it assumes a closed surface. The surface given in cylindrical coordinates by
$$
\left\{ \begin{align*}
r &= 5 \\
z &\in [0,2] \\
\theta &\in [0,2\pi)
\end{align*} \right.
$$
is not actually closed: it is a cylinder that is missing its top and bottom surfaces. That is, your surface is only the lateral surface of the cylinder

whereas the entirety of the closed cylinder would also adjoin $r \in [0,5]$ for $z = \{0,2\}$:

I imagine if you calculated the flux through those two caps individually, too, you would find the errant  $100\pi$ units of flux, since the flux you calculated via the parameterization (the lateral surface), plus those through the top and bottom surfaces, should sum up to the flux through the newly-closed surface formed by adjoining all three pieces (which you can get via the divergence theorem).

Also, a minor issue, but your stated $\mathbf{n}$ does not have unit magnitude, that was merely the cross product, but this did not affect the $400\pi$ calculation (i.e. I think it was a typo as you wrote up the post, not in the calculation).
